# client can read the message from the socket sometimes but cannot read the same message sometimes

Tags: c++, sockets

Below code is the client side and the server side is given in binary format thus server side cannot be modified . I can modify only client side. Client and server send messages to each other respectively.

i take the example code from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm and make slight changes .It can be compiled.When multiple clients are connected to the server , in some cases client can read from socket,however, in some cases client cannot read from socket. In other words, in the line

```
n = read(sockfd,buffer_reader,255);
```

running is stacked at this point and 
    it is waiting without giving any error. I cannot find any reason why it 
    works sometimes and it doesn't work sometimes although in both situations
    the message which will be send by the server is the same . I cannot find any 
    cause to this problem so cant produce any solution
 Here is the code. What may be the problem ?What can cause this problem?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

void error(const char *msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(0);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
u sing namespace std;
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    unsigned char hash[20];
    int src[2] ;
    char buffer[256];

if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

portno = atoi(argv[3]); 
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
server = gethostbyname(argv[2]);

if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
}

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;  //classic

    bcopy((char *)server-> h_addr,
    (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length  );
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    error("ERROR connecting");

while(1)
{
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer_reader,256);   
    fgets(buffer_reader,255,stdin); 
    n = write(sockfd,buffer_reader,strlen(buffer_reader)); 
    if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");

    bzero(buffer_reader,256); 

    n = read(sockfd,buffer_reader,255);  //problem arise here. Stacked here
    if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
    printf("The incoming message: %s",buffer_reader);
}
close(sockfd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your sockets are blocking. If there's nothing to read then the `read` call will block until there's something to read. Open your favorite search engine and search for "non blocking socket".

Comment: Not only that, but `recv()` is being asked to read 255 bytes. If the server sends fewer bytes, `recv()` can block waiting for data that will never arrive. Switching to non-blocking is one option, but I think the root issue is that the client is simply not looking for any kind of end-of-message condition, whether that be a message length preceeding a message, or a terminator sequence after the message. So unless messages are exactly 255 bytes every time, then this is not a well-designed client in general, regardless of the IO model used.

Comment: How can i check end of message while I cannot read anything from the server? In addition , when another client send some message to server in some conditions, it pass the stacked line . IN these conditions , the message received from server is not synchronous. In other words , i get the previous message's reply.